# Is it a red flag if a faculty offer is rescinded during negotiations, then reinstated when I agree to accept it on the spot?

Tags: united-states, job-search

Shortly after interviewing for a tenure-track Assistant Prof. position at a public R1 university, the Dept. Chair called to inform me that they were planning to make me an offer. After 4-5 email exchanges over 2 days in the form of negotiations, he wrote to me essentially saying that they had decided to move on to other candidates, and wishing me the best for the future.

I quickly replied, essentially apologizing for negotiating, after which he *reinstated* (his intent to make) the offer, should I *immediately* confirm my acceptance of his terms, *which I did*. I have now received the formal offer letter.

About the negotiations: I was never rude, and never suggested that any of my declined requests were dealbreakers for me. However I did ask politely for numerous standard things, including a higher salary, an additional teaching release, and additional startup and relocation funds. I did this in steps: for example, when a higher academic salary was partially declined (a small increment was indeed approved), I asked for a month of summer salary for the first two years. This was also declined.

I am trying to understand if this is alarming, and if so, how alarming it is. Personally, I feel terrified, but R1 TT offers are not easy to come by.

My question is whether all this is very unusual & alarming, as something I should factor when considering the written offer.

Comment: It sounds like the chair is bad at negotiating.  What is your question?

Comment: Sounds like: the chair had no extra money to provide, but then--when you kept asking for more--he decided you were unobtainable.

Comment: This is a Q&A site. You do not seem to have a question in your post.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: wouldn't it be that he's very good at negotiating, since I ended up dropping my requests so as not to lose the offer? My question is about if this is alarming, as something I should factor when considering the written offer.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: updated post to ask a question. It does ask for an opinion, but that is unavoidable...

Comment: Ok: unless you receive a competing job offer with a better deal, you do not have any real alternatives. While the situation is indeed unusual, there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @VelvetGhost No, that's not true.

Comment: It's common for applicants who want more time to secure a better offer to look for ways to delay their decision about an earlier offer.  Because you kept asking for additional adjustments in the deal, it may have appeared that your negotiation was actually a delaying tactic.  The chair's insistence that you *immediately* accept the final offer makes this seem likely.

Comment: The fact that you apologized for negotiating and then immediately accepted the original offer suggests that you didn't really have any leverage to negotiate with, in the sense that you weren't actually willing to walk away from this if your conditions weren't met. You were essentially called on your bluff.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: I know very well that I didn't have leverage. I did not pretend to have other offers, or threaten that I would decline the offer, so there was no "bluff" here. Many candidates who do not have leverage in the form of alternate offers, still do negotiate. They make it clear that they want to accept, but are requesting extra stuff for specific reasons. The question is whether it's ethical to revoke an offer as a negotiation tool. As others have suggested, I could have instead been given a "take it or leave it" choice.

Comment: You miss my point - if the stuff you negotiate for is important to you, then you *should* be prepared to walk away, nothing wrong with that. Maybe that's how they saw it. Maybe it initially appeared to them that "take it or leave it" was not an option because of how you presented your case. Even if you did explicitly say that you are willing to go with the original offer, maybe they missed that. The only reason their actions can be seen as a "negotiation tactic" is because *you called them back*. So, was rescinding the offer unethical? I'm not sure there's compelling evidence to think that.

Comment: I understand, but even if they felt I would decline the offer, I don't see why giving me a short time (even 1 day) to formally accept or decline, was not an option. After all, their eventual reinstatement of the offer proves that even while revoking the offer, they had NOT decided that they could absolutely not hire and work with me me under any circumstances.

Answer (score 12):

> I am trying to understand if this is alarming

It may be alarming, but it’s worth considering that your own behavior might have been perceived as alarming from the department’s point of view. Specifically, you said that you asked for several things “in steps”. It’s hard to say how problematic this is based on the details you provide, but if you mean that you repeatedly presented new requests after your earlier requests were answered (either positively or negatively), then this might be a form of moving the goalposts or negotiating in bad faith, which are not standard or particularly accepted practices in negotiations. This or other things may have been interpreted by the chair as a signal that you are an unreasonable person or someone who would be difficult to work with.

The bottom line is, rescinding an offer is indeed unusual, but there are times when it actually makes sense when a hiring prospect behaves in a way that reflects poorly on them. I can’t say if your situation is of this type. If you’re going to get upset about the chair’s behavior, you may want to make sure first that your own behavior was reasonable and didn’t give the chair some good reasons to behave the way they did.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I was never rude and never implied that I might decline the offer. I provided reasonable reasons for every (reasonable) request, and was not negotiating in bad faith. I did indeed do a bit of "goalpost moving", but only when previous requests were declined. I was trying to present them with alternatives that they could/would accept. It seems a stretch to conclude I would be a bad colleague, based on just my negotiations. And again, the offer was reinstated after all, contradicting even that conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is whether all this is very unusual & alarming

> After 4-5 email exchanges over 2 days in the form of negotiations, he wrote to me essentially saying that they had decided to move on to other candidates, and wishing me the best for the future.

Yes, that's unusual and alarming.  You would not "move on" unless it was obvious an agreement will not be reached.  Five emails is not much in a negotiation.

> something I should factor when considering the written offer.

No, the competence of the chair at negotiating should not be an important consideration for you when deciding on the final offer.  (possible exception: The chair is a professor in a business school.)

When you negotiate, sometimes you are negotiating with a fool.  The fool thinks they are right and you are wrong, so they do not realize they are in a situation where negotiation is appropriate.  I have met several fools who are professors.  Blue-collar workers are usually smarter at negotiating.

If you find yourself in the chair's place, say:

> I am sorry, but the dean is not going to approve any of the things you have requested.  Will you accept the offer we are able to make?

Do ask the dean for the things before refusing to give them.